# how to change number of segments

Tags: modeling

I need to find these settings in blender 2.8. When you add new object (Blender 2.79) you have this object settings, botom left. But in version 2.8 I can't find it.

I need to change sphere/cylinder segments in blender 2.8.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's still in the bottom left in the 3d view area. A little rectangle only one line text you have to open it to configure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 2.80 the panel to adjust the last operator has been moved out of the toolbar region into a floating panel at the bottom left of the viewport. This can be expanded/collapsed by clicking the top of the panel.

[image: adjust last operator panel]

There is an option to hide this panel, it can be found in the 3D viewports View menu.

[image: Viewing the adjust last operator]

Even if the last operator panel is hidden, we can still bring it up manually with <kbd>F9</kbd> - note that in 2.79 we use <kbd>F6</kbd>

Comment: thank you, that answer is perfect.
for some reason i'm not allowed to choose an answer to my own question...